Mentioning researcher unrelated to institution I'm applying for in motivation letter
I am writing a motivation letter for a scholarship to fund my MS thesis project at university X. However, my research interests are inspired by the work of a researcher working at a completely unrelated university Y.
I know that in my motivational letter it would be best to mention a university X researcher who works in a similar area, as this would display interest/familiarity with both the field an the institution, but I have yet to find one whose work would align with my interests as well as the unrelated researcher does. The choice is then between misrepresenting my interests and (potentially) getting rejected because of a perceived lack of interest towards the university I am applying to. The third alternative is mentioning no one, and just describing my interests in an abstract way, although I feel that would come across as a little impersonal. What should I do?

Yes, that's fine as long as you make it clear that you think University X is a good place to carry out your plan. In math, it's very common to come up with a research plan extending the well-known recent work of some famous person, A. If university X has a professor, B, who also seems interested in the work of person A, then it would be entirely appropriate to describe the research you hope to do, and make a connection to the work of person B. This is very common. It's more of a web of connections between research groups and universities, and less about one university monolith vs another university monolith.
